# Lenovo ThinkBook - HDD Password : Frozen

Tags: hard-drive, bios, uefi, password-protection

Context:
I received a laptop from my work and then was allowed to just keep it. They asked for it back to wipe the data etc and then gave back to me.
I decided to reset it just so it's all mine.

Problem:

In the BIOS,

**HDD Password : Frozen**

Shouldn't it be Set/Clear? Why is it Frozen?

**Secure Boot doesn't get disabled**. I have set the Admin Password and tried to keep Disabling it. But no go.

Any work around this problem? I know in most cases, the hard disk will need to be replaced. But just checking.

EDIT : Bold and small edit.

Comment: Are you entering BIOS settings from a reboot or from a fresh power-on?

Comment: Did you ask your place of employment for the password?

Comment: Sometimes if secure erase fails drive remains in this state. You can try hook up drive to other PC and run Victoria for Windows. Else get new drive.